# Mac: reloading document in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, applescript

How can I tell Chrome or Firefox to reload the document in the top window?  Here's what I'm using for Safari:

```
osascript -e '
    tell application "Safari"
      activate
      do JavaScript "history.go(0)" in document 1
    end tell
'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not think Firefox or Chrome have special Applescript support, but  you can send the keystrokes (Cmd-R) to refresh the page:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: Firefox is supposed to but it's been broken with current 3.5.x releases, apparently.

Comment: Nifty!  This works for all three browsers, using "Firefox", "Google Chrome", and "Safari" as application strings.

Answer (score 40):

Here's the code for Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell the active tab of its first window
        reload
    end tell
end tell
```

Or more concisely:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window
    reload
end tell
```

Comment: This script deserves more upvotes IMO because it doesn't require you to bring the Browser into focus before reloading - This is key.

Comment: You can also use "first tab" instead of "active tab."

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to do it in Safari without using JavaScript:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell its first document
        set its URL to (get its URL)
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

## Automator

- Open *Automator* and choose a  <kbd>New Document</kbd>
- Choose <kbd>Service</kbd>

[image: A screengrab showing the document type dialog in Automator]

- Set *Service receives* to <kbd>no input</kbd>
- Choose <kbd>Run AppleScript</kbd> action from the action list.
- Paste the following code in the script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window
reload
end tell
```

[image: A screengrab showing the automator window actions]

- Save the the service, for example, using the name <kbd>Chrome Refresh</kbd>

## System Preferences

- Open *System Preferences* > *Keyboard*
- In the *Shortcuts* tab, choose <kbd>Services</kbd>
- Assign a new shortcut

[image: A screengrab showing System Preferences keyboard shortcut tab]

Answer (score 0):

The following answers above work well but using them result in DevTools refreshing in a new tab if it was the last tab/window in focus. I don't want DevTools to refresh in a new tab, I just want the first tab to refresh regardless of last focus/active and this worked well for me.  Leaving for someone searching for this use case as well.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
  activate
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
      keystroke "r" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```