# auto-reload html file with a browser via terminal command

Tags: html, macos, bash, unix, terminal

I am trying to do some small html web stuff, and would find it incredibly useful to be able to see live updates of the html file viewed through a browser whenever I save my file. I know there are probably IDEs out there that do this for you, and if you recommend any, please do, but I am looking to make a script that will just open the file in the browser, while closing the version of the file that was already open, so that I can continue to do all my programming in vim.

I know that I can use the following in Mac OSX, to open the file into a new tab of my current browser:

```
open foo.html
```

but, if I have this occurring on a timed loop, or every time I write (:w) in vim, my browser will fill up with new tabs. Is there a way to close the old tab when opening the new tab? Or is there an even better approach to this that I have not considered? It would be highly preferred if I could continue to use vim in terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found some alternative solutions/kluges here: [/r/commandline](http://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1gdi4e/im_stumped_anyone_know_how_to_autoreload_an_html/)

Comment: This solution does not use the command line but you could add a little JavaScript that reloads the page using `location.reload();` every so often and turn it on only during development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is already a tab for `foo.html`, `open foo.html` should focus that tab in Safari. For Chrome, you might use something like this:

```
set u to "http://t.co/"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 0
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            set i to i + 1
            if URL of t is u then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                tell t to reload
                activate
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    open location u
    activate
end tell
```

I have just assigned ⌘R to `open "$TM_FILEPATH" -a Safari` in the `text.html` scope in TextMate. I have also enabled saving documents when switching to another application, so it basically does the last three steps of the edit-save-switch application-refresh cycle.

Other options:

- http://livereload.com
- http://brettterpstra.com/2011/03/07/watch-for-file-changes-and-refresh-your-browser-automatically

Comment: AppleScript support is a moving target, but this script works for me out-of-the-box with macOS 10.12.6 and Chrome 62. The first run loads, the second refreshes -- even if I'm on another tab. Great! ... It does not work if I have switch to another window, however -- it finds the correct tab number, then reloads it in the current window.

Answer (score 12):

You can use AppleScript to reload the tab. See the Benjie's answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091235/mac-reloading-document-in-chrome-or-firefox)
Use `osascript` to call the AppleScript from shell script. You'll get something like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window to reload'
```

Alternatively you can use something like next to close all previous tabs:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set windowList to every tab of every window whose URL starts with "http://stackoverflow.com"
    repeat with tabList in windowList
        repeat with thisTab in tabList
            close thisTab
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Only refresh the first tab of your Chrome :                                                       `osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the first tab of its first window to reload'`

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for your application, but I use make files for all my HTML projects. I only make static sites for myself, but I use Less and Jade (sometimes php compiled to static pages locally, it is silly that you can't dynamically include with jade) and make is really well integrated with vim. You can make rules for compiling, reloading, pushing to server, whatever.  The way I get live updates to the browser is to start a Node or python server to serve the html with an extra javascript 'watcher' there are lots of varieties, depending on what other technologies you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can get yourself a browser that can receive commands from a socket, like uzbl, luakit or dwb.

You can add this functionality (listening to a socket, or even a file) with an extension (addon, plugin, whatever your favorite browser calls it).

You can insert some javascript to the page you are editing, that will make it reload upon some signal you can control from the CLI.

You can write a script that will kill the browser and reopen it. Some browsers will try to load a cached version of the page. For these you better use the query string and create a unique URI each time (e.g. `open "foo.html?$(date +%s)"`).

The possibilities are endless!