# Send KeyEvent to a Target window via process Id

Tags: swift, cocoa, events, macos-sierra

I need to create a key event (cmd + r for refresh for the browser window) and pass the process Id for the window I'm trying to target. Let's say

```
    let customEvent = NSEvent.keyEvent(with: NSEvent.EventType.keyUp,
                     location: NSPoint(),
                     modifierFlags: NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command,
                     timestamp: TimeInterval(),
                     windowNumber: 0,
                     context: NSGraphicsContext(),
                     characters: "",
                     charactersIgnoringModifiers: "",
                     isARepeat: false, 
                     keyCode: 0x0F);


    let cgEvent = customEvent!.cgEvent

    cgEvent!.postToPid(688) // I want to post to a process with pid 688
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case all you need to do is to call *postToPid* on your *CGEvent* instance, and pass the PID as argument:

```
let cgEvent = customEvent!.cgEvent
cgEvent?.postToPid(168)
```

**Edit**
Your code doesn't work because you're just sending a key up event, not CMD+R. You can do this easily in AppleScript. See this question: [Mac: reloading document in Chrome or Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091235/mac-reloading-document-in-chrome-or-firefox)

**Edit 2**

Without AppleScript, this is how I would do it:

```
let src = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
if let event = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x0f, keyDown: true)
{
    event.flags = .maskCommand
    event.postToPid(your_browser_pid)
}
```

Successfully tested with Safari.

Comment: thanks, how do I get the pointer to the process serial number, let's say PID from activity monitor I see is 631

Comment: and it's actually a key event, not a mouse event

Comment: can you please explain how I make this work `CGEvent.postToPSN()`, the process PID is 168, how do I get process serial number and pointer to this process

Comment: I misunderstood your question: I thought that you wanted to translate literally the code in the other question. But in your case it's enough to call *postToPid()* on your *CGEvent* instance (see the edit).

Comment: the browser in this case Firefox is not getting refresh command for the loaded window, can you please try on your end with a web browser

Comment: I suggest to use AppleScript for that. If you need to integrate this piece of code into an application,  you can run AppleScript code from a Swift/Objective-C project.

Comment: I'm looking into Apple Script, I never used it but going to look into it, but for the sake of completion since we did almost 90% of work already, can we please finish this piece. if you can please take my code and make it work with a browser and refresh the loaded page. Thanks.